# Is there a way to access value of constant memory bank in CUDA

Tags: cuda, ptx, cuda-gdb

I have been trying to debug cuda programs that use inline PTX assembly.  Specifically, I am debugging at the instruction level, and am trying to determine the values of arguments to the instructions. Occasionally, the disassembly includes a reference to constant memory.  I am trying to have gdb print the value of this constant memory, but have not found any documentation that shows how to do this.
For instance, a disassembly includes
IADD R0, R0, c[0x0] [0x148]

I want to determine how to have gdb print the value of c[0x0] [0x148].  I have tried using print * (@constant) ... but this does not seem to work (I pass 0x148 here and it prints out nothing).  Is this possible to do in cuda-gdb?

I have tried to avoid this by passing the compiler option --disable-optimizer-constants during compilation, but this does not work.

Comment: You can use `cuobjdump --dumpelf` and look a the constant sections (`.nv.constant0.*` for `c[0x0]` and `.nv.constant2.*` for `c[0x2]`.

Comment: @njuffa The constant bank can change on kernel launch, for instance, to pass parameters in.  What I am trying to do is create a script that logs the values of operands to instructions before they are executed.  The elf file won't help me with this.

Comment: If I knew how to do what you want to in `gdb`, I would have written answer. *One* of the constant banks is used to pass kernel arguments, correct. And you can copy data to `__constant__` data, which uses a different constant bank. Most apps do not update `__constant__` data. The compiler puts literal constant into yet another constant bank. Looking at the `elf` sections lets you at least look at all constant bank data that does not change dynamically, which should be better than no visibility at all.

Comment: Since those places are constant, can't you just print the values before the point where you're stepping through individual instructions?

Comment: @einpoklum I need to be able to get an on-the-fly mapping between the constant bank references and the system variables before hand.  It's not clear how to access these mappings from within gdb.

Comment: Why do you need any on-the-fly mappings? If you're not sure which constant will get used, print a bunch of them (well, unless the printing affects what gets used later on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to
print *(void * @parameter *) addr

where addr is the address inside the constant bank 0 that should be printed.

#### Example

Suppose we have a simple kernel in a file called `foo.cu`:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void myKernel(int a, int b, int *d)
{
    *d = a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if (argc < 3) {
       printf("Requires inputs a and b to be specified\n");
       return 0;
   }

   int * dev_d;
   int d;
   cudaMalloc(&dev_d, sizeof(*dev_d));
   myKernel<<<1, 1>>>(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), dev_d);
   cudaMemcpy(&d, dev_d, sizeof(d), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   cudaFree(dev_d);
   printf("D is: %d\n", d);
   return 0;
}
```

which is compiled via

```
$ nvcc foo.cu -o foo.out
```

Next, suppose we are interested in disassembling this program, so we execute `cuda-gdb` with a command-line for our program:

```
$ cuda-gdb --args ./foo.out 10 15
```

Inside `cuda-gdb`, we get to the kernel by typing

```
(cuda-gdb) set cuda break_on_launch application
(cuda-gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x000055555555b12a in main ()

(cuda-gdb) cont
```

Inside the kernel, we view the disassembly we are interested in debugging:

```
(cuda-gdb) x/15i $pc
=> 0x555555b790a8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+8>:  MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20]
   0x555555b790b0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+16>: MOV R0, c[0x0][0x144]
   0x555555b790b8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+24>: MOV R2, c[0x0][0x148]
   0x555555b790c0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+32>:
   0x555555b790c8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+40>: MOV R3, c[0x0][0x14c]
   0x555555b790d0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+48>: IADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x140]
   0x555555b790d8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+56>: STG.E [R2], R0
   0x555555b790e0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+64>:
   0x555555b790e8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+72>: NOP
   0x555555b790f0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+80>: NOP
   0x555555b790f8 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+88>: NOP
   0x555555b79100 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+96>:
   0x555555b79108 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+104>:        EXIT
   0x555555b79110 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+112>:        BRA 0x70
   0x555555b79118 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+120>:        NOP
```

The second argument being passed to the `IADD` instruction is in one of the constant memory banks. Let's find out what its value actually is. We advance go to the `IADD` instruction:

```
(cuda-gdb) stepi 4
0x0000555555b790d0 in myKernel(int, int, int*)<<<(1,1,1),(1,1,1)>>> ()
(cuda-gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x555555b790d0 <_Z8myKerneliiPi+48>: IADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x140]
```

We can now obtain the contents of `c[0x0][0x140]` as follows:

```
(cuda-gdb) print (int) *(void * @parameter *) 0x140
$1 = 10
```

Here, we knew the argument should have 32 bits, so we cast it as an (32-bit) `int`. If we hadn't done this, we would get too many bits, e.g.:

```
(cuda-gdb) print *(void * @parameter *) 0x140
$2 = 0xf0000000a
```

Note the hexadecimal format can be retained by adding /x after the `print` command:

```
(cuda-gdb) print/x (int) *(void * @parameter *)0x140
$3 = 0xa
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting here. Remember, even though you're answering yourself - you have to target your answer at other people who don't have the same context as you.

Comment: What do you mean?  If an instruction references c[0x0][0x140] then to print the value being passed to the instruction, you use 
print *(void * @parameter  *) 0x140

Comment: Please provide a concrete example with PTX instruction and the sequence of commands and outputs with cuda-gdb.

Comment: @einpoklum I've edited the answer with a concrete example and the sequence of commands and outputs in cuda-gdb.  Does it look better as an answer?

Comment: Yes. I've tweaked it a little. However, the example is a much better answer than the first few paragraphs. I would retain perhaps just the second line of the answer and say the example explains what I mean. If you like, I could make that edit. Anyway, now you have two upvotes from me.